# In Jaspersoft Studio, how to change number of pages

Tags: jasper-reports

I am creating a report in jasper studio which contains only one chart. But when i click on preview tab it creates the chart on hundreds of pages. And the chart is same on every page. Can any one tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you put the chart in the Detail band. The Detail band gets repeated for every record in the database. Try putting the chart in the page footer, it only gets repeated every page. If your report is supposed to have a lot of pages, try putting it in the report footer, which only prints once, at the end of the report.

I have a feeling it won't work in the page header or report header because they seem to be created before data is queried.